# mysql query with left join and a combination of AND and OR in the where clause

Tags: mysql, left-join, combinations, where-clause

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2` who are `LEFT JOIN`ed. There should be a query with a combination of `AND` and `OR` conditions on both tables. Preferable in one single query. I'm aware that I could do several queries and intersect the arrays of id (with PHP) but ...

---

#### `table1`:

```
id     email    status
1      a@one    1
2               1
3      b@two    1
4      c@three  0
5      d@four   1
6      e@five   1
```

---

#### `table2`:

```
ix   t_id    type     value
1    1       1        Miller
2    1       2        10001
3    1       3        x
4    1       5        y
5    2       1        Miller
6    2       2        20002
7    2       3        x
8    3       1        Muller
9    3       2        10002
10   3       5        x
11   4       1        Mayer
12   4       2        10002
13   4       3        x
14   5       1        Moore
15   5       2        10234
16   6       1        Zlo
17   6       2        12345
18   6       3        x
19   6       5        x
```

---

I need a query, where I want all id's of active persons (`status=1`) where there is an email (all in `table1`), the name of the person (type 1) must begin with M `AND` the zipcode (type 2) must begin with 1 `AND` they have either type 3 being an x `OR` type 5 being an x (all in `table2`).

There should be no id returned, if there isn't `EITHER type = 3 OR type = 5` entries.

There should be no id returned if `type = 3` or `type = 5` but neither value is `x`

---

In my example:

```
t_id 4 (Mayer) ist not active, so he should not be in the result
t_id 2 (Miller) has no email, so he should not be in the result
t_id 5 (Moore) does not have type 3 and does not have type 5 so he should not be in the result
t_id 6 (Zlo) the name does not begin with M so he should not be in the result
```

I managed to write something like this but it does not work at all zero lines:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table2 
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON (t_id = id WHERE email LIKE '%@%' AND status = '1') 
WHERE (type = 1 and value LIKE 'M%') 
AND (type = 2 AND value LIKE '1%') 
AND ((type = 3 AND value = 'x') OR (type = 5 and value = 'x'))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

THANK YOU RiggsFolly

After the nice Help it would be (and works)

```
SELECT id 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.userid = table1.id 
AND status = 1 AND email LIKE '%@%' 
WHERE ( 
(type = 3 AND value = 'X') 
OR (type = 5 AND value = 'X') 
)
```

The additional conditions of `table2` can't be integrated and will be separate queries:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.userid = table1.id 
AND status = 1 AND email LIKE '%@%' WHERE (type = 1 AND value LIKE 'G%')
```

and

```
SELECT id 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.userid = table1.id 
AND status = 1 AND email LIKE '%@%' WHERE (type = 2 AND value LIKE '1%')
```

Comment: If the stuff after the "thank you" is the answer, it doesn't belong in the post, post an answer instead of putting it in the question post. Either way, it's not clear what it's doing there. Also when asking about code give a [mre]. Also there is no question in this post. If you are asking about wrong code, give the 1st expression returning what you don't expect & say what you expected & why. Otherwise show what parts you can & can't do & research what you are stuck on.  [ask] [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically type cannot be 1 and 2 and 3, but it could be 1 or 2 or 3

```
SELECT id 
FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.t_id = t1.id AND status = '1'
WHERE t1.email LIKE '%@%'
AND (
        (t2.type = 1 and t2.value LIKE 'M%') 
    OR  (t2.type = 2 AND t2.value LIKE '1%') 
    OR  (t2.type = IN(3,5) AND t2.value = 'x')
    )
```